# !children.any((Widget child) => child==null) is not true

Tags: null, dart, flutter, children

I am getting this error (image of: [the actual error on running in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOTgX.jpg)) when I am building the Row and filling it with different Icons according to the values in a particular list which I have.
Here is the part of code: 
(Note I am returning some widget in both the cases!)

```
 new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 19.0, 0.0, 19.0),
          child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children:
              (ballwiseDetails.length==0)?(List<Widget>.generate(6,(index) {
                setState(() {
                  return new Icon(Icons.add);
                });
              })):
                  List<Widget>.generate(ballwiseDetails.length,(index) {
                setState(() {
                  (index >= (6 * (overNumber - 1)))
                      ? (getIcon(ballwiseDetails[index].ball["TypeOfBall"])):null;
                });
              })
              ))
```

getIcon Method:-

```
Container getIcon(case_Each_Ball ib) {
String text = "O";
switch (ib) {
  case case_Each_Ball.dot:
    text = "O";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.Singles:
    text = "1";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.Doubles:
    text = "2";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.Triples:
    text = "3";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.Four:
    text = "4";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.Six:
    text = "6";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.WD:
    text = "WD";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.WD4:
    text = "4WD";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.Five:
    text = "5";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.OUT:
    text = "OUT";
    break;
  case case_Each_Ball.NB:
    text = "NB";
    break;
  default:
}
return new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: (ib == case_Each_Ball.OUT)
          ? Colors.red[800]
          : Colors.yellow[800]),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: new Text(text),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Agree with @aziza's answer. I think you don't have to put `return new Icon(Icons.add)` inside `setState()`. Similarly one more setState()

Comment: I added that line cz i thought the error was due to the fact that the length of the ballwiseDetails list is always zero at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Make your last `else` condition not return `null`, return an empty `Container()` instead.

```
(index >= (6 * (overNumber - 1)))
                      ? (getIcon(ballwiseDetails[index].ball["TypeOfBall"])):Container();
```

Comment: I exactly wrote this now. But I'm getting the same error

Comment: Then i wrote return new Container () ; instead of jst Container (); Cz  I realise i hav to return something. But still no results!!Same error!

Comment: check your code, it is very simple you must always return some widget/s with every condition, if you are getting your list through a network request make you sure you have some sort of a place holder

Comment: List<Widget>.generate((ballwiseDetails.length==0)?(6):(ballwiseDetails.length), (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (ballwiseDetails.length == 0) {
                        return new Icon(Icons.add);
                      } else if (index >= (6 * (overNumber - 1))) {
                        getIcon(ballwiseDetails[index].ball["TypeOfBall"]);
                      } else {
                        return new Container();
                      }
                    });
                  })
                  )

Comment: Thats wha tI did. I am returning something for almost everything. Checkout ^